# QML - Custom Scrollable Text Area for Multi Touch application

Tags: qt, qml, drag

With multiple ScrollView/Flickable components, the dragable area is capture in one component at a time.
I've managed to come up with a solution:

```
Item {
Rectangle {
    id: container
    width:300
    height:200
    clip: true

    anchors.left: parent.left;
    anchors.topMargin: 5;
    anchors.bottomMargin: 5;
    anchors.rightMargin: 5;
    anchors.leftMargin: 5;

    Text {
        id: contentText
        width:parent.width-45
        wrapMode: Text.Wrap
        font.pointSize: 10
        text: qsTr("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. <br><br>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. <br><br>It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br><br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br><br>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.")
    }
    DragHandler {
        target: contentText
        xAxis.maximum: 0
        xAxis.enabled: false
        yAxis.minimum: -contentText.height + container.height
        yAxis.maximum: 0

    }
}
ScrollIndicator {
    active: true
    orientation: Qt.Vertical
    size: container.height / contentText.height
    contentItem: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 6
        implicitHeight: 100
        radius: width / 2
        color: "#a9a9a9"
    }
    position: -contentText.y / contentText.height
    anchors { top: container.top; right: container.right; bottom: container.bottom }
}
}
```

https://github.com/j04ntoh/QtMultitouchQml
You can also download the sample from my github.